# Como estabelecer uma comunicação, em um mesmo arquivo, entre múltiplas tags PHP

Tags: php, html, orientação-a-objetos

Boa noite.
A questão é a seguinte, estou fazendo um programa de conta bancária, em que primeiro, em um arquivo.html, eu recupero alguns dados via formulário, e os envio para um outro arquivoX.php. Neste mesmo, além de recuperar os dados digitados pelo usuário, eu criei um objeto "conta1", cuja classe está definida em um outro arquivoY.php.
O que fiz agora foi fechar a tag php do arquivoX, criar um formulário para depósito ou saque de valores, e abrir uma nova tag para que nesta eu recupere estes dados, e realize as operações de get e set com o objeto. O problema é que nesta nova tag o objeto "conta1" não é reconhecido, e então gostaria de saber como faço para resolver isso.

```
<?php
    
        $tipo_conta = isset($_GET["tipo_conta"]) ? $_GET["tipo_conta"]: null;
        $cpf_cliente = isset($_GET["cpf_cliente"]) ? $_GET["cpf_cliente"]: null;
        $nome_cliente = isset($_GET["nome_cliente"]) ? $_GET["nome_cliente"]: null;

        require_once 'Conta_bancaria.php';
        if($tipo_conta != null && $cpf_cliente != null && $nome_cliente != null){
            $conta1 = new Conta_bancaria($tipo_conta, $cpf_cliente, $nome_cliente, "não definida", null, true);
        }
        print_r($conta1);
        $conta1->setNum_conta("450-12");
        echo "<p> O número da conta foi definido e é {$conta1->getNum_conta()}.</p>";
        if($tipo_conta == "CC" || $tipo_conta == "cc"){
            $conta1->setSaldo(100);
        }
        else if($tipoconta == "CP" || $tipoconta == "cp"){
            $conta1->setSaldo(150);
        }
        echo "<p> Por ser um conta do tipo {$tipo_conta} o saldo inicial padrão é de {$conta1->getSaldo()}.</p>";
        echo "<p> Senhor(a) {$conta1->getDono()}, veja abaixo os dados atualizados de sua conta bancária: </p>";
        print_r($conta1);
    
    ?>
    </pre>
    
        <p id = "aviso"> Depósito ou saque </p>
        <form method = "get" action = "?"> 
            Se for depositar, informe o valor a ser depositado: <input type = "number" name = "deposito" /> </br>
            Se for sacar, informe o valor a ser sacado: <input type = "number" name = "saque" /> </br>
            <input id = "botao_enviar" type = "submit" value = "Enviar"/>
        </form> 
        
    <pre>
    <?php /* AQUI FAREI OPERAÇÕES DE MUDANÇA DOS DADOS DO SALDO COM OS VALORES DE DEPOSITO OU SAQUE */
        $deposito = isset($_GET["deposito"]) ? $_GET["deposito"]: null;
        $saque = isset($_GET["saque"]) ? $_GET["saque"]: null;
        require_once 'Conta_bancaria.php';
        
        if($saque == null && $deposito == null){
            echo "<p> Nenhum valor foi digitado </p>";
            exit();
        }
        else if($saque != null && $deposito != null){
            echo "<p> ERRO! Não é possível depositar e sacar simultâneamente </p>";
            exit();
        }
        else if($deposito != null && $saque == null){
            /* depositar*/
        }
        else if($deposito == null && $saque != null){
            /*sacar*/
        }
     ?>
```

Comment: Pensei agora na possibilidade de passar o objeto da primeira tag como "parâmetro referência" para um método do arquivo da classe, e recuperar um "clone" do objeto chamando a mesma função na outra tag. Seria possível?

Answer (score 0):

Olá...

Se você quiser manter o objeto '$conta1' entre as requisições, terá que salvá-lo em algum lugar, possivelmente nesse caso, o ideal é o superglobal **$_SESSION**.

Faça o seguinte:

```php
    // no começo do script
    session_start(); //para iniciar a sessão

    //antes de criar um objeto, veja se ele já existe. Se não existir, crie-o
    require_once 'Conta_bancaria.php';
    if(isset($_SESSION['conta']){
        $conta1 = $_SESSION['conta'];
    } else {
        if($tipo_conta != null && $cpf_cliente != null && $nome_cliente != null){
            $conta1 = new Conta_bancaria($tipo_conta, $cpf_cliente, $nome_cliente, "não definida", null, true);
            $_SESSION['conta'] = $conta1;
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Estou aprendendo PHP, acabei querendo dar uns passos a mais durante um vídeo de getter setter e constructor, trazendo a inserção de dados por HTML.
Mas essa solução que tu me deu acho que entendi, na sessão em que farei os getter e setters para depósito e saque, que serão chamadas para modificação do método saldo, eu defini que esta mesma sessão será igual a sessão anterior que foi igualada ao objeto '$conta1'.

Comment: Na primeira tag PHP, basicamente criei o objeto, no bloco de código do else do if, e fiz isto: $_SESSION['conta'] = $conta1;
Foi o que eu entendi do que dissestes.
Já na segunda tag PHP, onde irei receber os dados de depósito ou saque, fiz o seguinte:
session_start();
$_SESSION['dep_saq'] = $_SESSION['conta'];
Isto é, esta nova sessão será igual a sessão anterior. É isso?

Comment: Mais ou menos isso. A sessão é um objeto que persiste no servidor enquanto o usuário está conectado. Caso não hajam requisições por um período especificado, ela expira, do contrário, cada vez que ela é acessada, esse período é renovado. Com o uso dela, você pode 'transferir' ou 'enviar/receber' dados entre páginas/requisições.